# validating JWT token on aws with https load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, asp.net-core, jwt, openiddict

I am using **aws(amazon web services)** to host my app . My hosting server has no SSL installed but **load balancer** (the internet facing gateway) has SSL so whenever I make call to `https:// mydomain .com` it first goes to load balancer and then `http:// mydomain .com`.

However the problem with this architecture is when server creates a token it has issuer `http:// mydomain .com` so in `jwtbeaererauthentication` configuration if I put `http:// mydomain .com` as authority it throws CORS error and if I put `https:// mydomain .com` it wont authorize.

If there is any workaround for this kind of issue please let me know. I am using **asp.net core, openiddict and jwtauthentication** as middleware.

Comment: Are you authenticating your users in your app or on a seperate authentication server?  It's my understanding that the `Authority` option is only required when running a seperate authentication server.  Therefore, you don't need to set the option if authenticating users in app.

Comment: hi thanks for reply , yes its on different server infact on two different servers